# How to add items to list from one single input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rekq2hr/)

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <input type="email" ng-model="newContact" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode==13?addContact():''"/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="email in newContacts">
            {{ email }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
angular
.module('test', [])
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newContact= 'somestring'
    $scope.newContacts = [];
    $scope.addContact = function() {
        $scope.newContacts.push($scope.newContact);
        $scope.newContact = '';
    };
})
;
```

But it isn't working as expected. I was expecting that the input would be pre filled with `somestring` But it will be empty.

The first time I hit enter (`keyCode==13`) on empty input `somestring` will be added to the list, even if I don't see `somestring` in the input field.

The second time I hit enter an empty string will be added, regardless of what I entered in the input.

If I change the input and hit enter, `null` or `''` will be added to the list.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input type is email, and you are passing a string that is not valid as email, for example in your fiddle if I change to text type it works as expected, or if you insert a valid email also works fine if you want to keep the input email type

Answer (score -1):

$scope.newContacts is empty. You are not iterating in your controller function.
you simply defined a function that is suposed to iterate or recourse an array, your not executing it.
you need to execute your inner function.